# The rpc server is unavailable (exception from hresult : 0X800706BA)

Tags: vb.net, excel

My application scan through the excel files and generate a report having count of Activex controls in each excel file. But while running the tool from client machine we are getting an error on opening the file (for some file not all) and the files are located in the sever side, as follows:

**"the rpc server is unavailable (exception from hresult : 0X800706BA)"**

Can you please guide me why this happens....

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its seems to be an well known error
[s. Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/935677/en-us)

Comment: That bug seems to be an issue only on Windows XP, and only seems to effect networks that disconnect a lot.

Comment: I had something like this and have searched for the answer. Than I have found this question and the information from MS Support )  It doesnt help me in my problem - but maybe someone else - that was the idea =)

Answer (score 4):

This usually occurs because the server you are communicating with has crashed.

Answer (score 3):

When you first launch Excel programmatically, it connects to Excel via an RPC server. When you close the document, this server gets closed without your application knowing about it.

The solution is to trap an error and re-initialise your Excel object. you will then be able to continue.

Comment: Launching Excel and connecting to Word!

Comment: Fixed. It was just a typo

Answer (score 0):

I had the same and exact problem and upon searching online, nothing works. So I tried one of the comments to open and close Excel both local and server and it works!

If you have the same problem, try to open Excel or the Excel file you are using and close it.

Then try to run your application again.